# Checking min no of characters in capturing group in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a question in regex

I am dealing with numbers 0 and 1 only

I have 10 digit number grouped into 4 as below

([01]{2})([01]{4})([01]{2})([01]{2})

I need to match all those numbers with min 2 1's in the second group which is ([01]{4}) , no matter how many 0's or 1's other groups are having. I am interested only in the second group

For example, these are the potential matches are

```
0000110000
0011000000
0001100000
0000110000
```

I tried using positive look ahead  like :

```
^(\d{2})((?=\d*1{2,}\d*)(\d{4}))(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

but this is matching even

```
0000000011
```

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you need only those occurrences where two `1`s are consecutive?

Comment: (([0]{0,})([1]{2,})([0]{2,})) how about this one?

Comment: Is `0010010000` valid, should it be matched?

Comment: Hi there, you unchecked the accepted mark. Did it not work out? Or is there any feedback for the posted answers?

Comment: Sorry for that. when I tested another scenario, it was not working .@Thefourthbird, I need to match the ones with consecutive 1s only. For your solution,
it was matching 0010010000 also

Comment: @sachintom Like this then? https://regex101.com/r/dpmCoP/1

Answer (score 1):

If the ones need to be consecutive (as per your sample data), maybe you can use:

```
^(?=[01]{2,4}11)[01]{10}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZklcTT/1). The idea here is that you would match 2-4 zero's or 1's upto a sequence of two ones. It makes sense if you realise the only combinations that are allowed would have the *minimum of two 1's* ("11") sequence after exactly 2-4 other digits.

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?=[01]{2,4}11)` - Open positive lookahead to look for 2-4 characters from our characters class upto "11".
- `[01]{10}` - Match exactly 10 characters from our character class.
- `$` - End line anchor.

If need be you can change the `[01]{10}` pieces where you'd use capture groups.

---

**EDIT:**

If they don't have to be consecutive, maybe you can work with:

```
^[01]{2}(?=[01]{8}$)([01]{0,2}1[01]{0,2}1[01]{0,2})[01]{4}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQbauC/1).

Or less verbose:

```
^(?=[01]{10}$)(..)(.*1.*1.*)(..)(..)$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/luNWEb/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the two `1`s are not necessarily consecutive in Group 2, you can use

```js
^([01]{2})(?=(?:[01]*1){2}[01]{4,6}$)([01]{4})([01]{2})([01]{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/krdiF7/2)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([01]{2})` - Group 1: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `(?=(?:[01]*1){2}[01]{4,6}$)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be two occurrences of any zero or more `0` or `1` chars followed with `1` and then there must be four, five or six `1` or `0` chars till the end of string
- `([01]{4})` - Group 2: four occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `([01]{2})` - Group 3: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `([01]{2})` - Group 4: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Not a job for regex but for bitwise operators:

*(in PHP)*:

```
$nums = [
    '0000110000',
    '0011000000',
    '0001100000',
    '1000110000',
    '0000000110',
    '0001000000'
];

foreach ($nums as $num) {
    if ( !in_array((bindec($num) >> 4) & 15, [0, 1, 2, 4, 8]) )
        echo $num, PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can probably do that in any language.

Answer (score 0):

If a positive lookahead is supported, you could also assert that group 2 has as least `11` using a positive lookahead.

```
^([01]{2})(?=[01]{0,2}11)([01]{4})([01]{2})([01]{2})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([01]{2})` - **Group 1**: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[01]{0,2}11` Match 0-2 times either `0` or `1` and match `11`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `([01]{4})` - **Group 2**: four occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `([01]{2})` - **Group 3**: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `([01]{2})` - **Group 4**: two occurrences of `1` or `0`
- `$` - end of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhhCvZ/1)

Or you can write out all 3 alternatives matching `11`

```
^([01]{2})(11[01][01]|[01]11[01]|[01][01]11)([01]{2})([01]{2})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vw3XqQ/1)